# ROLLBACK undo redo

Tags: java, copy, binary-tree, undo

I'm building a database using a BST (binary search tree) and I want the user to be able to roll back the last 5 commands. Any Suggestions? I'm using Java.

Comment: How big is the tree?  If it is small enough you could just keep a copy for the last 5 operations.

Comment: Not very big. How would I cop that lat 5 operations??

Comment: @user475529: don't keep the last five operations, copy the whole tree after every operation and keep the most recent five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Berkey DB? It's free and supported nested transactions (which would allow you to have any number of levels of rollback):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg_txn/JAVA/nestedtxn.html

Even if you decide to implement your own DB, it might be useful as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).  Essentially, you create an object that has all of the information required to:

1. From the state of the tree before the operation, repeat the operation. (Redo)
2. From the state of the tree after the operation, revert the operation. (Undo)

You'd keep the last five of these around.  When the user asks for an undo, take the latest, ask it to revert the operation, then indicate somehow (some index variable, for example) where you are in the list of mementos.  You should then be able to move through the list in either direction, undoing and redoing as much as you want.

Comment: I was thinkin to insert my tree into a stack the pop it when the user calls to undo?? Is that possible?/

Comment: You could do that of course, but using a memento you will save a lot of space while still allowing undo/redo functionality.